# Amazon Load Balancer gives out Error 503

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, https, wordpress

My website is currently on HTTP only. The route to my website is like this: DNS (Route53) -> Server (Amazon EC2 running LEMP stack and WordPress).

Now I'm trying setting up TLS encryption on the website. I've decided to make a certificate on ACM and use it for a new load balancer. The route will be:
DNS -> Load Balancer (with HTTPS listener) -> Server (still HTTP).

I've successfully created the load balancer. Health check passed (Ping target: `HTTP:80/license.txt`). I update the DNS to point to the load balancer.

As the certificate is for `www` version of the site, I've configured NGINX to force `www` and updated WordPress URL (`https://www.example.com`).

Now the site is giving out Error 503 (Back-end server is at capacity). Is there anything to be done on server or load balancer?

Comment: You need to trace things through the stack and see where the error is being generated. Could be the ELB health check. Could be the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect directly to the server?.
I doesn't look like an ELB problem it looks like an instance/server problem.

The 503 description quote:

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle
>   the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the
>   server.

It looks like there is a problem with your Web Server

Comment: I've tried connecting to the server directly, via its Public DNS. As I've updated WordPress URL, it's giving out 301 Moved Permanently.